# Can we copy audio recording file from device document directory to outside in desktop

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudiorecorder

Hello everyone I recorded a sound file and stored in device document directory. Now I want to copy this audio file in system anywhere.It is possible or not because I want to use recorded audio in any where  another project. I need this file really. 
So please help me

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAudioMemo.m4a"];
BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
if (exists) {
      NSLog(@"exist");
    BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:@"/Users/talnetlgia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E8C88799-DDD9-41DB-8C26-6A5EF556A8A2/data/Containers/Data/Application/0DB5C306-B62F-4582-8222-C337423B8526/Documents/MyAudioDemo.m4a" error:nil];
    NSLog(@"copy success....%d",success);

}
else{
    NSLog(@"does not exist");

}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing???

Comment: I am not getting audio file at destination path. Value of Bool is No after run copyItemAtPath method. I want to tell you one thing that I run the project on iPhone device.

Comment: This is possible. Have you checked the path on your desktop?

Comment: Yes I checked, first thing is that mehtod's return value is NO and also checked manually but not get file on destination path. Please tell me how can I do it successfully

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should map the document directory. Only then you will be able to save it on your desktop.

```
NSString *path = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] path];
NSString *audioPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAudioMemo.m4a"];
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:audioPath error:nil];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I didn't get very well can u explain more